# What might prevent ADB from writing to a Settings.Secure key?

Tags: adb, settings, bugs, gestures, google-camera

I am trying to edit the value of a Secure Settings key over ADB with the command:

`settings put secure camera_double_twist_to_flip_enabled 1`

For some unknown reason, the value of this key is `0` and cannot be changed. Because of this, the shake gesture in the Google Camera app does not work.

I've tried a number of fixes, all with no success:

- `settings put --user 0 secure camera_double_twist_to_flip_enabled 1` : Fails to set value.
- `settings put --user 10 secure camera_double_twist_to_flip_enabled 1` : Successfully sets value for the Work Profile (aka user 10), but doesn't affect the Personal Profile (user 0) where Gcam is installed). There are no other profiles set up.
- `settings put secure camera_double_twist_to_flip_enabled default` : Value remains at `0`.
- **Settings > System > Languages & input > Advanced > Flip camera** : No such toggle exists in the Settings app.
- **Settings > System > Gestures > Flip camera for selfie** : No such toggle exists in the Settings app.
- Boot into **Safe Mode**, then `settings put secure camera_double_twist_to_flip_enabled 1` : Successfully sets value, but only temporarily. When phone is rebooted into Regular Mode, the key value is RESET TO `0`.

The device is an unrooted Google Pixel 7 running GrapheneOS 13 (a ROM very similar to stock AOSP).

This issue is being discussed on the [GrapheneOS development forum](https://discuss.grapheneos.org/d/3214-twist-to-flip-frontback-camera-feature-missing), where a different user running GrapheneOS 13 on a Google Pixel 6 did *not* encounter the same issue and was able to set the key value via ADB as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I had the app [SystemUI Tuner](https://github.com/zacharee/Tweaker/) installed, which can manage such settings and apparently had a way to make its own preferences persist even if a setting were changed by another method, including ADB.